# How to add auto increment number to select tag?

Tags: php, html

```
$x = date("");

function add_nol($number,$add_nol)
{
   while (strlen($number)<$add_nol)
   {
      $number = "0".$number;
   }

   return $number;
}

for($y=10;$y<=50;$y++)
{
   echo "<select name='id'>";
   echo "<option value='". $x."".add_nol($y,3)."'>" . $x."".add_nol($y,3) ."</option>";
   echo "</select>";
}
```

I want to add auto increment numbers into select tag, but I am getting drop down for each numbers from the above code. How to fix this error?

Comment: be more specific, what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Two things to remember:

- The [`<select>`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/select) element is used to create a drop-down list.
- The [`<option>`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/option) tags inside the `<select>` element define the available options in the list.

With your current code, the generated HTML markup would be similar to this:

```
<select name='id'>
    <option value='010'>010</option>
</select>
<select name='id'>
    <option value='011'>011</option>
</select>
...
```

This is incorrect. You are creating a separate dropdown on each loop iteration. You only need one `<select>`tag - they should go outside the loop.

```
echo "<select name='id'>";
for($y=10;$y<=50;$y++)
{
    echo "<option value='". $x."".add_nol($y,3)."'>" . $x."".add_nol($y,3) ."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/E0nWRo)

Comment: thank you, how to cleare the auto increment number from drop down once it is used..?

Comment: @user3312405: Sorry, what do you mean by *auto increment number*?

Comment: sorry for english.... i have 100 numbers in drop down . once i select a number, that number must not be present in the drop down for the next time.

Comment: @user3312405: That should be posted as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You are repeatedly creating the `select` tag inside the loop , thats y the select boxes are created instead of option tags. Edit the for loop as:

```
echo "<select name='id'>";
for($y=10;$y<=50;$y++){       
    echo "<option value='". $x."".add_nol($y,3)."'>" . $x."".add_nol($y,3) ."</option>";      
}
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: how to cleare the auto increment number from drop down once it is used..?

Comment: What you meant by `once it is used?`

Comment: i mean once i submit a number from drop down... next time it must not appear in that  drop down box

Comment: @user3312405 are you storing that value in database.?